# Sickipedia Style App for Photos

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a sickipedia style app, but with photos rather than jokes. The idea is that someone can upload a photo, it can be commented on, voted on (up and down), there is a latest section and a top section.

If anyone knows of any tutorials or how I can go about this, it would be very much appreciated.

I am looking to make this an Android app

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a concept of how your app will look like and fit together it should become easier to develop an app that functions like sickipedia.

1. First of all notice the platform that sickipedia uses. There's is a side navigation tab and a tab at the top. The side navigation tab links the user to various activities.
2. Download Android SDK developer tools
3. Draw out on a sheet of paper various screens (activities) and linking them to one another to show the flow of user activity.
4. Start building your app piece by piece

I would start by looking here for sample code:

https://android.googlesource.com/

**EDIT**: since you will be uploading photos instead of text, I would start by looking here and exploring the `MediaStore` class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

[Build a photo upload application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042416/build-a-photo-upload-application-in-android)